# Exceptions handler for getenv()

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, securityexception

How can I handle `NullPointerException` and `SecurityException` for that kind of line code:

```
public final static String PROJECT_DIR = System.getenv().get("HOME") + "/Projects/MyTestProject";
```

It will be sufficient to just wrap it with `try/catch`? If so how I can differ it will be `NullPointerException` or `SecurityException`?

Also are there any best practices to have it stored in properties if `getenv()` is not available or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `final static String` in the class initializer. Throw a new exception describing the problem (not set, not allowed). For example:

```
public final static String PROJECT_DIR;

static {
     try {
       Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();

       if (!env.contains("HOME")) {
           throw new AssertionError("HOME not set as environment variable");
       }

       PROJECT_DIR = env.get("HOME") + "/Projects/MyTestProject";
     } catch (SecurityException e) {
       throw new AssertionError("Security policy doesn't allow access to system environment", e);
     }
 }
```

Comment: `System.getenv().get(key)` throws an NPE if key is not set. This code would work for `System.getenv(key)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner You are right, checked the JavaDoc, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would throw both NullPointerExceptions and SecurityExceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


      System.out.println("System.getenv("HOME") = ");
      System.out.println(System.getenv("HOME"));
```